# max-height in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with `columns` flex direction and 3 divs in it. The first and the third div take as much height as their content takes, while the second one (which I'll call `A`) takes the remaining space. It should be obvious, but I'll add it anyways. `A`'s height is unknown.

Inside `A` I'll have a random number of images with unknown width/height. All those images will occupy a single row (just like a carousel). The images must:

- occupy the biggest possible area of `A`, but
- keep their aspect ratio, and also
- don't occupy more than 1/3 of the width of the visible area of `A`, and also,
- no gaps between the images

The second requisite I could easily accomplish with `max-width: 33%`, but the first one is not that easy. It seems that `max-height: 100%` is being ignored.

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/oxqBPv

And here is the expected result:

```
|-------------------------------------------------|\
|                                                 | \
| |---------------------------------------------| |  \
| | up                                          | |   \
| |---------------------------------------------| |    \
|                                                 |     |
| |---------------------------------------------| |     |
| |                  @@@@@@@@@                  | |     |
| |                  @@@@@@@@@                  | |     |
| | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ | |     |
| | @@@@ 33 % w. @@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@ 33 % w. @@@ | |     |
| | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ | |     400px
| |                  @@@@@@@@@                  | |     |
| |                  @@@@@@@@@                  | |     |
| |---------------------------------------------| |     |
|                                                 |     |
| |---------------------------------------------| |    /
| | down                                        | |   /
| |---------------------------------------------| |  /
|                                                 | /
|-------------------------------------------------|/
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope now it is what you wanted to achieve: http://codepen.io/kbkb/pen/jqzBKJ

You where missing a `height` to the containing `div`. The `max-height` didn´t know what `100%` is because the parent element had no height. ( i now set 88% height because it was what was fitting, but you should determine the height of up and bottom and substract them from 100% e.g. `calc(100% - 20px)).

With `text-align:center` i am then centering the images.

Also i added `box-sizing: border-box` this solves the problem that when you have an element with height X and add a border of 1 px you would have height: X+2. Trough `border-box` the border applies inside the element not outside on top of the height.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but... this isn't working as expected. The wrapper has 400px and the images are overflowing that height.

Comment: Hm no... i did not saw that requirement... but this is impossible without chaning the aspect ratios and `height: 400px; width: 1200px;`

Comment: Why? The only thing that is failing is the `max-height` at the bottom of my CSS code. I'm sure there must be some other way of achieving this.

Comment: But in your plunker the image in the middle is over 400px? Maybe i don´t unterstand what you want to achieve. I updatet my plunker to have a height of 400px by changing the width

Comment: No, the image could have any height/width. I want the max-height of each image to be 100% of `A`. Said with other words, adapt to the height of `A`.

Comment: No. That solution is completely rubbish. I don't know the height of the div.